# Представление ячейки в формате тыс. Power bi

Tags: excel, powerbi

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в отчете таблицы представлять данные с приставкой тыс. млн. и тд

Без DAX и формул, а какой нибудь кнопочкой

Прим: 1 245 678 ----->  1 245 тыс.

Answer (score 0):

Пользовательский формат вводим через диалоговое окно Формат ячеек.

1. для вызова окна нажмите CTRL+1;
2. выберите (все форматы), удалите все из поля Тип;
3. в поле Тип введите:   [>1000000]#,0 " млн";[>1000]#,0 " тыс.";# ##0,00

Ответ взят с сайта [excel2.ru](https://excel2.ru/articles/otobrazhenie-v-ms-excel-chisel-v-formate-millionov-i-tysyach) (вроде бы в комментарии его неправильно вставлять, поэтому решил создать ответ)

Также информация по правилам создания пользовательских форматов: [support.office.com](https://support.office.com/ru-ru/article/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-c0a1d1fa-d3f4-4018-96b7-9c9354dd99f5)  и есть масса информации на множестве сайтов.